# Flask stream/multipart file from S3

Tags: python, flask, boto3, wsgi, zappa

I'm using Flask in AWS Api Gateway/Lambda environment (Thanks to Zappa), but there is a limit in response size, so Flask's `send_file` is not enough in this context.

Is there a way I can stream/multipart(not sure if these are the correct terms) a file-like object as response in Flask? I can't send request bodies with more than **5mb**(6mb?) in the AWS Serverless environment.

Current code (simple S3 proxy that deletes the object once downloaded):

```
@app.route('/polling/<key>')
def polling(key):
    obj = BytesIO()
    try:
        s3.download_fileobj('carusoapi', key, obj)
        s3.delete_object(Bucket='carusoapi', Key=key)
        return send_file(obj, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=key)
    except Exception:
        return 'File not ready yet', 204
```

I've seen some examples [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/) but don't understand how to apply them or if that's even what I'm looking for.

I also noticed that boto3 S3 module has options like callback for `download_fileobj` [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) and you can specify chunksize [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig), but again, I don't understand how to apply this to a Flask response.

I know of a way to solve this that involves sending a signed download link to the client to download the item, but then I would have to implement in the client to delete the file.

Comment: Have S3 serve the data *directly* to the client, don't stream it through Flask, with a presigned URL. See the duplicate, the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls) and perhaps the [Flask-S3 project](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which automates this for you via a `url_for()` wrapper.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mentioned I'm aware of this solution in my last paragraph

Comment: Why would you need to have the client delete the file when it's a S3 link? Just have a batch process clean up S3 buckets.

Comment: Better yet, [set a lifetime cycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html), and have Amazon take care of cleaning up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Already set that up, the minimum is 24H, in my case the file will be in "limbo" for 1 day after the client received and downloaded it, so I just wanted to know if I could delete it just after the client downloads it, just an ideal scenario.